# Node file system fs.exist strikethrough

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, fs

This backend code retrieves an image file from the uploads/users folder. Visual Studio Code marks fs.exists with strikethrough, what does it means? It's deprecated? How can i replace this? Thanks in advance.

```js
getImageFile: (req, res) => {
        let file = req.params.image;
        let pathFile = './uploads/users/' + file;
    
        fs.exists(pathFile, (exists) => {
            if(exists){
                return res.sendFile(path.resolve(pathFile));
            } else {
                return res.status(200).send({message: 'No existe la imagen'});
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `fs.exists` is deprecated, one reason is that

> The parameters for this callback are not consistent with other Node.js
> callbacks. Normally, the first parameter to a Node.js callback is an
> err parameter, optionally followed by other parameters. The
> fs.exists() callback has only one boolean parameter.

[Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback) is pretty clear about this and recommended alternatives (`fs.stat` and `fs.access`)

The real problem in your code is the race condition you could encounter in your callback if for example that file gets deleted meanwhile. A safest way would be:

```
res.sendFile(path.resolve(pathFile), function (err) {
    if (err) {
        if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
            return res.status(200).send({message: 'No existe la imagen'});
        }
        else {
            // handle other errors...
        }
    }
})
```

Other common system errors are [here](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors).

Answer (score 1):

Probably because [`fs.exists` is deprecated](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback) and you shouldn’t use it in new code.